# Function not excuting as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, function, foreach

I have a function, InsertItems:

```
    public void InsertItems()
    {
        todoitemList.Clear();
        todoSelect.Items.Clear();

        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ToDoList/ToDo"))
        {
            ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem();

            item.ID = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText;
            item.Title = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Title").InnerText;
            item.Description = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Desc").InnerText;
            item.PriorityLevel = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Priority").InnerText;
            item.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Date").InnerText);
            item.TimeHour = Convert.ToInt32(xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("TimeHour").InnerText);
            item.TimeMinute = Convert.ToInt32(xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("TimeMinute").InnerText);
            item.TimeSecond = Convert.ToInt32(xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("TimeSecond").InnerText);
            item.Completed = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Completed").InnerText;

            todoitemList.Add(item);
            todoSelect.Items.Add(item.Title);
            todoIDList.Add(item.ID);
        }
    }
```

This function clears both a list and the combo box to which is used to select the items and then fills the list with the relevant data. ToDoItem is a class which contains properties - ID, Title and so forth.

When the function is executed within Form1.cs, it fully works as expected, clearing the list and adding the new data. However, when the function is executed within Form2.cs (main.InsertItems()), the foreach loop appears to be never ran and I've really no idea what is causing this.

Any help is much appreciated!

--

Edit:

main.InsertItems() is called in the following function:

```
    private void createNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckAll())
        {
            XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ToDo", null);

            XmlNode xmlNodeID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ID");
            xmlNodeID.InnerText = CreateRandomID();

            XmlNode xmlNodeTitle = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Title");
            xmlNodeTitle.InnerText = textBoxTitle.Text;

            XmlNode xmlNodeDesc = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Desc");
            xmlNodeDesc.InnerText = textBoxDesc.Text;

            XmlNode xmlNodePriority = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Priority");
            xmlNodePriority.InnerText = Convert.ToString(priorityLevel.SelectedItem);

            XmlNode xmlNodeDate = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Date");
            string currentDate = Convert.ToString(monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start);
            string strippedDate = currentDate.Substring(0, currentDate.Length - 8);
            strippedDate += timeHour.Text + ":" + timeMinute.Text + ":" + timeSecond.Text;
            xmlNodeDate.InnerText = strippedDate;

            XmlNode xmlNodeTimeHour = xmlDoc.CreateElement("TimeHour");
            xmlNodeTimeHour.InnerText = timeHour.Text;

            XmlNode xmlNodeTimeMinute = xmlDoc.CreateElement("TimeMinute");
            xmlNodeTimeMinute.InnerText = timeMinute.Text;

            XmlNode xmlNodeTimeSecond = xmlDoc.CreateElement("TimeSecond");
            xmlNodeTimeSecond.InnerText = timeSecond.Text;

            XmlNode xmlNodeCompleted = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Completed");
            xmlNodeCompleted.InnerText = "False";

            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodeID);
            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodeTitle);
            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodeDesc);
            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodePriority);
            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodeDate);
            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodeTimeHour);
            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodeTimeMinute);
            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodeTimeSecond);
            xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlNodeCompleted);

            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlNode);

            try
            {
                xmlDoc.Save(_fileName);
                MessageBox.Show("Item successfully added!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                main.InsertItems();
            }
            catch (XmlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! The item could not be added due to an XML error.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! The file could not be found or written to. Item could not be added.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! An unknown error occured. Item could not be added.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

CheckAll returns a boolean -> true if all fields are valid.

_fileName variable is correct and is saving to the correct file.

Comment: Can you post the code from Form2 that you use to call `InsertItems` on Form1?

Comment: I have updated the main post.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# -" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not reloading `xmlDoc` in `Form1.InsertItems`.

In the code you posted, before calling `Form1.InsertItems` from `Form2`, you write the file to disk, but since you're not passing a reference to the updated `xmlDoc` from `Form2` on to `Form1`, you don't see the changes show up on `Form1`. `InsertItems` works as expected when you call it from `Form1` because `xmlDoc` is a member variable for `Form1`, so the changes are available in `InsertItems` when called from `Form1`.

Try either reloading the `XmlDocument` from the file system at the beginning of `InsertItems` or pass an `XmlDocument` to `InsertItems` as a parameter.

Comment: I had previously tried passing the filename through and then creating a new instance of XmlDocument but this did not work. I have just tried passing through the xmlDoc and again hasn't updated the combo box. I'm slowly running out of possible ideas! I can't see any obvious reason as to why it isn't running as expected.

Either way, it is adding the new items to the file as xmlDoc.InnerText.Length increases, and both the list and combo box are clearing. This means the foreach loop is obviously working as the old items are present. 

Why the new item isn't added I've now no idea!

Comment: What does the new Xml document look like? If the new elements aren't showing up then it must be because they don't match the xpath query you are using: `"ToDoList/ToDo"`. Are they being inserted into the Xml document in the proper location?

Comment: Also, when you say passing the filename through and creating a new instance of XmlDocument did not work, how exactly did it not work? Where you seeing the same behavior, getting an exception, etc...?

Comment: I ended up throwing it all into one form and taking it from there. I tried several methods and I think the main problem was the item was not being added to the drop-down menu. Even doing dropdown.Items.Add("test") wasn't added to the dropdown. Many thanks for your time and help though, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is the other class running on another thread? This could be due to a cross-thread exception. Basically, there is only one UI thread to update UI elements. If you try to update UI elements from another thread, then you will get an exception. It is possible that you are just swallowing that error. You can try debugging it and you will see the exception before it is eaten. If that is indeed the case, then you will need to Invoke back onto the UI thread to perform the update.

[Here is a good article on winforms cross thread UI updates.](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx)

Here is a rough example of what your code would look like (it is not compiler checked, but should be close :))

```
if ( main.InvokeRequired ) {
    main.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(main.InsertItems));
} else {
    main.InsertItems();
}
```

Comment: I'll have a read tomorrow and see if anything comes from it. Thanks!